# Is there a way to make constructor assignments more concise (and simple)?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

I was messing around with ES6 syntax today, and made up this basic test class:

```
class Animal {
  constructor(type, age, name = "Unnamed Animal") {
    this.type = type;
    this.age = age;
    this.name = name;
  }
  talkToMe() {
    console.log(`Hi, my name is ${this.name}, and I am a ${this.type}!`);
  }
}
```

Is there a way to make the constructor more concise using new ES6 syntax? Something, perhaps, like

```
constructor(type, age, name = "Unnamed Animal") {
    this = {type, name, age};
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I was going to say "no" because I was pretty certain that you have code as simple as it needs to be, but then I remembered [`Object.assign`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/assign) and the ability to use [object constructor shorthand syntax](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Object_initializer#New_notations_in_ECMAScript_2015).

If you've got a *lot* of properties to set, you can assign them all like this:

```
constructor(type, age, name = "Unnamed Animal") {
  Object.assign(this, {
    type,
    age,
    name
  });
}
```

This *will* come at a performance hit, and I think it's about equal as far as readability is concerned, but if typing `this.prop = prop` is annoying to you, this *is* an alternative.

Personally, I'd stick with:

```
this.name = name;
this.age = age;
this.type = type;
```

Comment: Meh, I've dropped my answer. But `Object.assign` isn't syntactic sugar, it's calling a function. I find a total overkill using this instead of `x = y` syntax...

Comment: @MatíasFidemraizer, The `Object.assign` call is new, and being able to use `{type, age, name}` to construct an object is also new ES2015 syntax, so it barely meets the requirements of the question. That said, I don't disagree with you. I hope my answer is clear on that.

Comment: Yeah, and I had to drop my answer because I would get more downvotes, while it was a right answer too: **No, and nothing is more concise than just an assignment.**. There're many other situations where you could use functions to simulate something that a programming language does in a very concise way already.... but if both the OP and other visitors are happy replacing an assignment with a function call, let's them be happy! :D

Answer (score 2):

You could do all three assignments at once with [Object.assign](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/assign):

```
constructor(type, age, name = "Unnamed Animal") {
    Object.assign( this, { type, name, age } );
}
```

Comment: Lots of good documentation about `Object.assign` is available at [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/assign) including a nice polyfill for when ES6 is not available.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can use `Object.assign`:

```js
class Animal {
  constructor(type, age, name = "Unnamed Animal") {
    Object.assign(this, {type, name, age});
  }
  talkToMe() {
    console.log(`Hi, my name is ${this.name}, and I am a ${this.type}!`);
  }
}
new Animal('elephant', '5', 'Dumbo').talkToMe();
```

There is a [proposal](http://wiki.ecmascript.org/doku.php?id=strawman:batch_assignment_operator) to allow something like

```
this .= {type, name, age};
```